# Character encoding causing RSA key recognition failure with Django/Docker/GoogleAuth/pythonRSA

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, rsa

I have a persistent error, in this case, when trying to run Django unit tests inside a container.

```
test_1          | Traceback (most recent call last):
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
test_1          |     sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
test_1          |     utility.execute()
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
test_1          |     settings.INSTALLED_APPS
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
test_1          |     self._setup(name)
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
test_1          |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
test_1          |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
test_1          |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_1          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
test_1          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
test_1          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
test_1          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
test_1          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
test_1          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
test_1          |   File "/advocate/advocate/settings/test-microservice.py", line 1, in <module>
test_1          |     from .base import *
test_1          |   File "/advocate/advocate/settings/base.py", line 378, in <module>
test_1          |     'client_x509_cert_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/{}'.format(get_env_setting('GS_CLIENT_EMAIL')).replace('@', '%40'),
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 193, in from_service_account_info
test_1          |     info, require=['client_email', 'token_uri'])
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 54, in from_dict
test_1          |     signer = crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_info(data)
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/crypt/base.py", line 115, in from_service_account_info
test_1          |     info.get(_JSON_FILE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID))
test_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/crypt/_python_rsa.py", line 174, in from_string
test_1          |     raise ValueError('No key could be detected.')
test_1          | ValueError: No key could be detected.
```

As I understand it, this happens when the google package tries to authenticate, but does not get a valid RSA key. In other, i.e. non-docker, contexts I have seen and resolved this error by changing the representation of the RSA private key's newline characters, depending on how it was being read in from the shell/file, etc. In some cases it needed `\n`, or `\\n`, or a literal newline.

In the current case, I have a `Dockerfile` and am using `docker-compose` to launch a container running unit tests. I am confident that `docker-compose` is providing the secrets from files. (Yes, that's what I want in this case, please do not bring up Swarm) If, for example, I comment out the line in the `.env` file with the secret key, `GS_PRIVATE_KEY=/run/secrets/GS_PRIVATE_KEY`, Django crashes with `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the GS_PRIVATE_KEY env variable`, so I know it is getting some plausible value set. All the other secrets are working fine. 
Since I believe from previous cases that this is caused by character encoding, I have tried every pairwise combination of (quotes, newline) in

```
[", ', `, <no quotes>], [\n, \\n, <literal return>, %0A]
```

All 16 versions of the private key file fail. I'm not sure what to try next, or how to coax more info out of my attempts.

(edited) SORT OF WORKING:
the solution that "worked" was to create another script, `set_key.sh` with

```
export GS_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat /run/secrets/GS_PRIVATE_KEY)
```

and to prefix each the entrypoint with `./set_key.sh &&`

This works when the key is in `\n` format

I don't really consider this an answer to the question, though, since this sure seems redundant. All the secrets are already being assigned to their relevant env vars in the `.env` file. Why would I need to overwrite that with the contents of `/run/secrets/GS_PRIVATE_KEY` *again*?